# docker container can't connect to localhost mysql server

Tags: php, apache, docker, mysqli

im new to docker, have tried to setup my docker php-apache container to connect to mysql db running on my localhost.  i created my docker image as follows:

dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

build new docker image:

```sh
docker build -t will-php-env .
```

my php application is placed in my home folder(/home/will/php/)

i run my container as follows:

```sh
sudo docker run -it -p 180:80 -v "$PWD":/var/www/html will_php_env
```

the code for connection is:

```php
mysqli_real_connect( mysqli_init(),"192.168.1.17", "root", "password", "bugtracker" );
```

error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.2' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/mantisbt-2.19.0/will.php on line 3

by the way, i will be able to connect to mysql server from the same container if i use the following code:

```
<?php 
$will2k =  new mysqli("192.168.1.17", "gkeepa", "password", "php");
```

please let me know why the container is not able to connect to mysql server on my localhost using mysqli_real_connect.  thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an entry in your `mysql.users` table for `root@172.17.0.2`

Comment: ... that or your root password is incorrect